# CSS - Keep hover state on "unhover"?

Tags: css, html, hover, transition

I have a row of 5 divs, and when you hover over one, it fills the width of the screen.[image: 6 Multicolored Divs]

The blue div fills the width of the screen by default; that way the screen is always full and I can apply css to shrink it down when I hover over the other divs because it is declared last in the HTML:

```
#green{
    width:20px;
}
#blue{
    width:100%;
}
#green:hover{
    width:100%
}
#green:hover ~ #blue{
    width:20px;   
}
```

Is there a way to keep one div open after it is "unhovered"? For example, if the orange div had been open and the mouse went off of it but NOT onto another of the colored divs, it could keep its full width. Currently, when the mouse rolls off, the divs slide back to blue.

Also, can I do this without any script?

Comment: Without any script? I don't think so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do it without javascript. But here is some sample code that you can use:

```
<div id="green" onmouseover="green()">foo</div>

<div id="blue" onmouseover="blue()">more foo</div>

<div id="pink" onmouseover="pink()">even more foo</div>
```

and the script:

```
function green() {
    $('div').css('width','20px');
    $('#green').css('width','100%');
}

function blue() {
    $('div').css('width','20px');
    $('#blue').css('width','100%');
}

function pink() {
    $('div').css('width','20px');
    $('#pink').css('width','100%');
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfect. I don't know any JavaScript, but I got it. I had to replace the lines that start with $ with "document.getElementById...", but otherwise, awesome!

Comment: If you don't have JQuery (the $) available, you might have to do a bit more conversion than that; one line might be "...byId('blue').style.width = '100%';". If it's working for you, you probably already figured that out though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it without a script by using CSS Animations.  See http://cdpn.io/GLjpK

It's not as reliable a method as using a script, but it is possible -- even keeping it after hover, which is the challenging part.